# How to get specific Values from a xml file with same Name in a element?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I don't know how to extract values from this specific XML document, and am looking for some help as I'm not very experienced on xml parsing.

I have to use `XDocument.Load` to load the file.

Actually i am using

```
doc = XDocument.Load(uri);
challenge = GetValue(doc, "Challenge");
```

this works without any problems, but how to get the inner values of the Element Rights ? (multiple "Name")
At the end of the day i need to now

```
Phone = x
Dial = x
HomeAuto = x
BoxAdmin = x
```

It’s also possible that some of the entries (Phone,Dial,HomeAuto,BoxAdmin) is missing. This
is dynamic.

Here is my xml File:

```
<SessionInfo>
 <SID>68eba0c8cef752a7</SID>
 <Challenge>37a5fe9f</Challenge>
 <BlockTime>0</BlockTime>
 <Rights>
  <Name>Phone</Name>
  <Access>2</Access>
  <Name>Dial</Name>
  <Access>2</Access>
  <Name>HomeAuto</Name>
  <Access>2</Access>
  <Name>BoxAdmin</Name>
  <Access>2</Access>
 </Rights>
</SessionInfo>
```

Edit: (Add GetValue method)

```
public string GetValue(XDocument doc, string name)
 {
   XElement info = doc.FirstNode as XElement;
   return info.Element(name).Value;
 }
```

Comment: Hey @DanB - side comment on your XML - you may be better off wrapping related Name and Access tags in a parent element, or having one `Right` element with `Name` and `Access` attributes.  That makes it very clear that there's a relationship between the two, and should make things a bit easier to work with.  Answer to actual question coming soon. . .

Comment: Posting the code for `GetValue` could be helpful as well.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - You have absolutely right, unfortunately  this xml is from a network device from a 3rd party, I can’t change the layout.

Comment: @Tim Ups, i update the question with the GetValue method

Comment: A typical job for XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB: this solution uses extension methods, so the using directives are important or you won't see the required functions.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        const string xml = "<SessionInfo><SID>68eba0c8cef752a7</SID><Challenge>37a5fe9f</Challenge><BlockTime>0</BlockTime><Rights><Name>Phone</Name><Access>2</Access><Name>Dial</Name><Access>2</Access><Name>HomeAuto</Name><Access>2</Access><Name>BoxAdmin</Name><Access>2</Access></Rights></SessionInfo>";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //loads xml from string above rather than file - just to make it easy for me to knock up this sample for you
            string nameOfElementToFind = "Name";
            IEnumerable<XElement> matches = doc.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//*[local-name()='{0}']",nameOfElementToFind));
            //at this stage you can reference any value from Matches by Index
            Console.WriteLine(matches.Count() > 2 ? "Third name is: " + matches.ElementAt(2).Value : "There less than 3 values");
            //or can loop through
            foreach (XElement match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                //or if you also wanted the related access info (this is a bit loose / assumes the Name will always be followed by the related Value
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", match.Value, match.XPathSelectElement("./following-sibling::*[1]").Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The important bit here is the line `IEnumerable<XElement> matches = doc.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//*[local-name()=\'{0}\']",nameOfElementToFind));`.  After the `string.format` takes place the XPath is `//*[local-name()='Name']`.  This XPath statement says to find all nodes with the name Name.  The `local-name()` function's there because we haven't said what schema's being used, in this instance we want any element called Name, regardless of schema.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nm.AddNamespace("eg", "http://Example/Namespace/Replace/With/Your/Docs/Namespace");
IEnumerable<XElement> matches = document.XPathSelectElements("//eg:Name", nm);
```

The double forward-slash says to search anywhere in the document.  To limit it to Rights you could say `/eg:SessionInfo/eg:Rights/eg:Name`.  In case you're unfamiliar with it, XPath's an awesome language / essential if you want to get the most out of working with XML docs.  If you have any questions about it please give us a shout, or have a look around online; there are great tutorials out there.

Comment: Minor suggestion:  "using statements" should be "using directives"; "using statements" are `using` blocks like `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())`, whereas "using directives" are for allowing the use of types in a namespace or to create an alias for a namespace.

Comment: Thanks @Tim - updated.  Sadly I'm not too hot on terminology.

Comment: This looks very promising, i will implement this today and report back. Many thanks for your help, this save´s me a lot of time. Great !